# Spring JWT in docker, returning 401, local works

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, docker-compose

i am using standart JWT auth, in Spring boot. When i run the app locally everything works fine, regarding auth to API endpoints, in postman. But when u built docker compose to move the app inside container with posgresql DB, i am getting 401 unatuhorized for every API i call. Does someone has hint why it might be happening? Thanks a lot !

Dockerfile for spring app

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Docker-compose

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: 'postgres:13.1-alpine'
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=compose-postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=compose-postgres
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  backend:
    image: 'docker-spring-boot-postgres:latest'
    build: ./backend
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/compose-postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=compose-postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=compose-postgres
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
    depends_on:
      - db
```

WebsecurityConfig

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
             
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll().and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate", "/api/customer/**", "/api/order/**").permitAll().
                // all other requests need to be authenticated
                        anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                        exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        
        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

JWT request filter

```
@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;

        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {

            UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time since this question was asked, but for if anyone had a similar problem this is as correct as possible.
The idea is not to accept keys created from another issuer.
This is the responsibility of the JwtValidator used in JwtDecoder.
However, if you don't want to use issuer for validation you can use NimbusJwtDecoder which is more configurable and doesn't use issuer for validation by default.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).